# Stripe Transfer API Using Rails for Marketplace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm creating a marketplace where a buyer pays for a sellers time. Once the seller marks the transaction as complete does the transfer begin.

I currently have the Stripe Charge & Managed Accounts set up already. Now I'm confused on how to integrate the transfer. The buyer gets charged, the money goes to the sellers account minus the fees.

I was thinking of adding a boolean called :complete_transaction and set it equal to false. Once the user clicks on a button that makes the boolean equal to true have a method that initiates the transfer.

Not sure if it works or how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go for two datetime fields `completed_at` and `compensated_at`. When the seller confirms completion you fill in the `completed_at` field and then a background job looks for transactions that were completed but not compensated (paid out by you) and makes transfers (updating `compensated_at` afterwards). This makes it way easier to debug in case any problems pop up.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure what you mean with filling out the completed_at field. What I've done so far and seems to work but not sure how good it is which is to create a sales history page with a "complete order" button. Once the seller clicks on it, it begins the transfer.

Comment: It's a pretty standard way to do it with Rails. Using diatomite field you know when a user clicked "completed" button which will help you a lot to understand what happened then something went wrong. If you are not familiar with concept of background jobs google will help you :)